# Not able to get the values of a sorted ag-grid column in an array using Protractor and Typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor, ag-grid

I have to verify the sorting function in an ag-grid.
When the UI is opened, the column data will be in some order.

I am sorting it in ascending order and then storing the values in a array.

```
ag_grid_utils.clickOnHeader("Name");
var testArr=[];
element.all(by.css('div.ag-body-container div[col-id="Name"]'))
    .map(function (Element) {
        element.getText().then(function (result) {
        console.log("result :: "+result);
        testArr.push(result);
    });
})
```

However when I print the array, the values are not sorted. They are in the same order like when I open the UI first time.

I have also added sleep statement after clicking on the header to verify the sorting in the UI. 
Is there anything I am missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my answer to this question. The question is slightly different but the answer applies here too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50149769/4125622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ag-Grid display sorted rows by **CSS** not by HTML **Node Position**. 
[image]

From above screenshot, we can see `Amelia Cage` is the first row after sort, but the HTML node of this row is not the first childNode of table body, but the last 2nd childNode of table body.

Also we can see the `css/style` of this row set `top: 0px` which means this row `position Y` relative to table body is `0`, that's why this row displayed as the first row even its HTML Node position is not first.

But `element.all()` return elements as order as their HTML Node position, so your 
`testArr[]` get same order as HTML Node position in HTML DOM Tree, rather than display order on page.

**Option 1)** order elements of `element.all()` by attribute `row-index`, then check the ordered array's text is with order or not. ( `row-index` more greater, row more near tail)

**Option 2)** order elements of `element.all()` by `top: yyypx`, then check the ordered array's text  is with order or not. ( `yyy` more greater, row more near tail)

Comment: Thank you Yong.I am able to fetch value by:
div.ag-body-container div[ row-index='4''] > [col-id='Name']